# Reducing boilerplate code in Hibernate repositories/using Spring's JpaRepository interface in a desktop client-server application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, desktop-application

I'm currently working on a desktop Java client-server application that uses Hibernate to access a database. Many of the calls to the database are generic CRUD operations and so I'd love a way to reduce the amount of boilerplate code.

I've stumbled upon the JpaRepository/CrudRepository interfaces in the Spring Framework and would like to be able to use either of them but it feels as though I'm constantly fighting against Spring's web-application focus. For instance, as repositories are autowired in by Spring, I'm not able to instantiate a copy or make a static instance and so it becomes difficult to call any of the repository's methods from the server class.

As such I have four questions:

1. Is there a way to use the Spring Jpa/CrudRepository interfaces
   without autowiring them in?
2. Is there a way to use either interface without using Spring?
3. Is there an alternative interface for desktop applications which would achieve the same purpose?
4. Is there a better alternative that I'm missing?

Comment: Spring Boot makes it really, really easy to launch a program inside a Spring context. I've used it for pure Web scrapers before.

Comment: How do you launch the program inside Spring boot? If I launch the server within a Spring Boot application either as a thread or an instance I get null pointer exceptions when attempting to use any repositories, and attempting to launch the server as a static means that its methods are not able to access the non-static repositories. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Make your "program" a Spring component; something simple like translating `main` to `@PostConstruct run()` to kick it off will usually work.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for your help! Whilst I have gone with the CommandLineRunner solution outlined by Jens, I tried your solution too and it worked nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrylis gave you the answer that you really need in the comments:

> Make your "program" a Spring component

I'd say the appropriate way to do that would be to make it a [`CommandLineRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html)

I'd even go beyond that and say: Even if you start you in a single process you should maintain a web like architecture, possibly even a web server in the application in order to

a) work with JPA in a reasonable way, i.e. have clearly defined requests that get processed by the server process in separate threads

b) do not block the UI while queries get processed.

To answer your literal questions:

> Is there a way to use the Spring Jpa/CrudRepository interfaces without autowiring them in?

Yes, you can manually create repositories using the [`JpaRepositoryFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/JpaRepositoryFactory.java)

> Is there a way to use either interface without using Spring?

The interfaces themselves are just interfaces and can be used without anything else from Spring. 
Of course the benefit of that is limited.

> Is there an alternative interface for desktop applications which would achieve the same purpose?

No, there is no need for that.

> Is there a better alternative that I'm missing.

I don't think so but I'm biased.

Comment: Thanks, the command line runner solution is working great!

"Even if you start you in a single process you should maintain a web like architecture, possibly even a web server in the application".

I'd like to move towards this but I assume it would require having the client (which I'd rather keep as a desktop app for now) send/receive web requests. As a new programmer I don't have any experience with that and I'm not sure where to begin but it's definitely an area I'd like to explore. If you've time I'd appreciate any resources/pointers on what I should be searching for/where to begin.

Comment: I think in your current position there is one thing you must understand in order to be successful with your application and that is the JPA life cycle. Understand how you don't need to save entities that got loaded from an EntityManager.

Also read up on REST while tossing aside all articles claiming REST can do without HATEOAS.

You probably won't be able to apply this to this project, but it will most likely help in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow with regards to not saving the entities - is that specific to a RESTful client impl? My current version requires saving the entity and then passing it as an object to the client. However, I am having some problems with this as once the connection is closed I am not able to get any of the attributes as even the primitive fields appear to be being loaded lazily. Is that what you were meaning and if so is there a workaround for my specific impl? The only way I can get it to work currently is by accessing the attributes before transferring the object to the client.

Comment: Try the following in a single transaction: load an entity, modify the entity, do not call `save`, `persist` or `merge`. Commit the transaction. Check the SQL log.